# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: no sessionId in returned payload - Moving from ruby 2.5.3. to 3.1.2

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber

Upgraded ruby from 2.5.3 to 3.1.2 and associated gems. Cucumber tests were running fine against v 2.5.3 on chrome but now getting the below error and stack trace. Also attached my gemfile.lock

SELENIUM BROWSER:   chrome
CHROME PATH:   /opt/google/chrome
CHROME DRIVER:   /home/####/git/se/acceptancetests/chromedriver

---

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: no sessionId in returned payload
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:57:in `create_session' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:313:in` block in create_bridge'
internal:kernel:90:in `tap' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:312:in` create_bridge'
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:36:in` initialize'
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in` for'
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.8.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:83:in` browser'
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:137:in `execute_script' /home/####/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:605:in` execute_script'
/home/####/git/see/acceptancetests/features/step_definitions/store_steps.rb:2827:in `wait_for_page_load' /home/####/git/se/acceptancetests/features/support/hooks.rb:18:in` AfterStep'

Gemfile.lock:

GEM
remote: ###
specs:
addressable (2.8.1)
public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
axe-matchers (2.6.1)
dumb_delegator (~> 0.8)
virtus (~> 1.0)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
builder (3.2.4)
capybara (3.14.0)
addressable
matrix
mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
nokogiri (~> 1.8)
rack (>= 1.6.0)
rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
xpath (~> 3.2)
coercible (1.0.0)
descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
concurrent-ruby (1.2.0)
cucumber (5.3.0)
builder (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.4)
cucumber-ci-environment (~> 9.0, >= 9.0.4)
cucumber-core (~> 11.0, >= 11.0.0)
cucumber-cucumber-expressions (~> 15.1, >= 15.1.1)
cucumber-gherkin (~> 23.0, >= 23.0.1)
cucumber-html-formatter (~> 19.1, >= 19.1.0)
cucumber-messages (~> 18.0, >= 18.0.0)
diff-lcs (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.0)
mime-types (~> 3.4, >= 3.4.1)
multi_test (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.0)
sys-uname (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
cucumber-ci-environment (9.1.0)
cucumber-core (11.0.0)
cucumber-gherkin (~> 23.0, >= 23.0.1)
cucumber-messages (~> 18.0, >= 18.0.0)
cucumber-tag-expressions (~> 4.1, >= 4.1.0)
cucumber-cucumber-expressions (15.2.0)
cucumber-gherkin (23.0.1)
cucumber-messages (~> 18.0, >= 18.0.0)
cucumber-html-formatter (19.2.0)
cucumber-messages (~> 18.0, >= 18.0.0)
cucumber-messages (18.0.0)
cucumber-tag-expressions (4.1.0)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
diff-lcs (1.5.0)
domain_name (0.5.20190701)
unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
dumb_delegator (0.8.1)
equalizer (0.0.11)
excon (0.98.0)
ffi (1.15.5)
headless (2.3.1)
http-accept (1.7.0)
http-cookie (1.0.5)
domain_name (~> 0.5)
i18n (1.12.0)
concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
ice_nine (0.11.2)
jwt (2.2.3)
matrix (0.4.2)
mime-types (3.4.1)
mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
mini_mime (1.1.2)
mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
multi_test (1.1.0)
mysql2 (0.5.5)
netrc (0.11.0)
nokogiri (1.12.5)
mini_portile2 (~> 2.6.1)
racc (~> 1.4)
parallel (1.22.1)
parallel_tests (3.13.0)
parallel
public_suffix (5.0.1)
racc (1.6.2)
rack (3.0.4.1)
rack-test (2.0.2)
rack (>= 1.3)
regexp_parser (2.6.2)
rest-client (2.1.0)
http-accept (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
netrc (~> 0.8)
rexml (3.2.5)
rspec (3.12.0)
rspec-core (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-expectations (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-mocks (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-core (3.12.0)
rspec-support (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-expectations (3.12.2)
diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
rspec-support (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-mocks (3.12.3)
diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
rspec-support (~> 3.12.0)
rspec-support (3.12.0)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-oci8 (2.2.12)
rubyzip (2.3.2)
selenium-webdriver (4.8.0)
rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
rubyzip (>= 1.2.2, < 3.0)
websocket (~> 1.0)
sys-uname (1.2.2)
ffi (~> 1.1)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext
unf_ext (0.0.8.2)
virtus (1.0.5)
axiom-types (~> 0.1)
coercible (~> 1.0)
descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
websocket (1.2.9)
xpath (3.2.0)
nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
ruby

DEPENDENCIES
axe-matchers
capybara
cucumber
excon
headless
i18n
jwt (~> 2.2.2)
mysql2
nokogiri (= 1.12.5)

Comment: WATIR is a wrapper around ruby selenium binding, install it and try again. If you still have the problem, raise your error by tagging watir tag.

Comment: @Rajagopalan there is no mention of watir. From the gemfile / stacktrace he is using capybara, which is the other major wrapper of the ruby bindings.

Comment: @LukeHill Oh yes, I know Capybara, since he hasn't included the capybara tag, I have asked him.

Comment: I get this on the upgrade as well, @hotspuds, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error here is indicative of you failing to generate capabilities correctly. So it's likely whatever updates you have done to selenium are now causing you to generate an invalid payload.

Around selenium 4alpha6 some large changes went in (So for v3 you could use `desired_capabilities` but now you simply use `capabilities`)

If you're using capybara you can use the gem here to just generate a simple driver in 1 click https://github.com/site-prism/automation_helpers/blob/main/lib/automation_helpers/drivers/local.rb#L7

EDIT: Your gems are a bit mismatched also. You're using an up to date selenium-webdriver but a really old version of capybara. See if you can keep those similar in age